# Why is gradle bdd command not working in the first run

Tags: spring-kafka

I delete topics and create using scripts in Dockerfile and start zookeeper and kafka. Next when running below command, process is stuck in first 2 runs and 3rd run is successful. Tested multiple times. Please let me know if any advice how to execute in first run.

```
./gradlew bddTest -Dspring.profiles.active=bdd --info
```

Comment: Can you please share the error or output you are getting after the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offsets were not reset in first two executions and error message relates to the same. Hence by setting property `auto.offset.reset` up to `earliest` in Kafka configuration at code level resolve the issue.

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```